# JSON object elements listed as undefined (tested both before and after using `jQuery.parseJSON()`)

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I'm trying to populate a dropdown list via iterating through a JSON object and appending the `value=` of each `<option>` with `row.id` and the actual value between the `<option>` tags with `row.name`.

**Edit**

I forgot to mention that the data being passed has been Ajaxed, and is the result of a PHP call to a database.

The problem is that, while the list is populated, each entry is listed as `undefined`. Ditto for the `id` as well. I must be doing this wrong, I'm just not sure what. This is the array I have:

```
    [{
    "id": "1",
    "0": "1",
    "parent": "0",
    "1": "0",
    "name": "Automotive",
    "2": "Automotive",
    "description": null,
    "3": null,
    "ordering": "0",
    "4": "0",
    "pub
lished": "1",
    "5": "1"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "0": "2",
    "parent": "0",
    "1": "0",
    "name": "Aerospace",
    "2": "Aerospace",
    "description": null,
    "3": null,
    "ordering
": "1",
    "4": "1",
    "published": "1",
    "5": "1"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "0": "3",
    "parent": "0",
    "1": "0",
    "name": "Agricultural",
    "2": "Agricultural",
    "description": null,
    "3": null,
    "ordering": "2",
    "4": "2",
    "published": "1",
    "5": "1"
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "0": "4",
    "parent": "0",
    "1": "0",
    "name": "Audiovisual",
    "2": "Audiovisual",
    "description": null,
    "3": null,
    "ordering": "3",
    "4": "3",
    "published": "1",
    "5": "1"
}, {
    "id": "5",
    "0": "5",
    "parent": "0",
    "1": "0",
    "name": "
Construction",
    "2": "Construction",
    "description": null,
    "3": null,
    "ordering": "4",
    "4": "4",
    "published": "1",
    "5": "1"
}, {
    "id": "6",
    "0": "6",
    "parent": "0",
    "1": "0",
    "name": "Energy",
    "2": "Energy",
    "description": null,
    "3": null,
    "ordering": "6",
    "4": "6",
    "published": "1",
    "5": "1"
}, {
    "id": "7",
    "
0": "7",
    "parent": "0",
    "1": "0",
    "name": "Electronics",
    "2": "Electronics",
    "description": null,
    "3": null,
    "ordering": "7",
    "4": "7",
    "published": "1
",
    "5": "1"
}, {
    "id": "8",
    "0": "8",
    "parent": "0",
    "1": "0",
    "name": "Electrical",
    "2": "Electrical",
    "description": null,
    "3": null,
    "ordering": "8",
    "4
": "8",
    "published": "1",
    "5": "1"
}, {
    "id": "9",
    "0": "9",
    "parent": "0",
    "1": "0",
    "name": "Entertainment",
    "2": "Entertainment",
    "description": null,
    "3": null,
    "ordering": "9",
    "4": "9",
    "published": "1",
    "5": "1"
}, {
    "id": "10",
    "0": "10",
    "parent": "0",
    "1": "0",
    "name": "Manufacturing",
    "2": "Manufa
cturing",
    "description": null,
    "3": null,
    "ordering": "9",
    "4": "9",
    "published": "1",
    "5": "1"
}, {
    "id": "11",
    "0": "11",
    "parent": "0",
    "1": "0",
    "name": "Medical",
    "2": "Medical",
    "description": null,
    "3": null,
    "ordering": "11",
    "4": "11",
    "published": "1",
    "5": "1"
}, {
    "id": "12",
    "0": "12",
    "parent": "0",
    "1": "0",
    "name": "Marine",
    "2": "Marine",
    "description": null,
    "3": null,
    "ordering": "12",
    "4": "12",
    "published": "1",
    "5": "1"
}, {
    "id": "13",
    "0": "13",
    "parent": "0",
    "1": "0",
    "name": "Home Applicances",
    "2": "Home Applicances",
    "description": null,
    "3": null,
    "ordering": "13",
    "4": "13",
    "published": "1",
    "5": "1"
}, {
    "id": "14",
    "0": "14",
    "parent": "0",
    "1": "0",
    "name": "Software",
    "2": "Software",
    "description": null,
    "3": null,
    "ordering": "14",
    "4": "14",
    "published": "1",
    "5": "1"
}, {
    "id": "15",
    "0": "15",
    "parent": "0",
    "1": "0",
    "name": "Theoretical work",
    "2": "Theoretical work",
    "description": null,
    "3": null,
    "ordering": "15",
    "4": "15",
    "published": "1",
    "5": "1"
}, {
    "id": "16",
    "0": "16",
    "parent": "0",
    "1": "0",
    "name": "Railroad",
    "2": "Railroad",
    "description": null,
    "3": null,
    "ordering": "16",
    "4": "16",
    "published": "1",
    "5": "1"
}, {
    "id": "77",
    "0": "77",
    "parent": "0",
    "1": "0",
    "name": "Chemistry",
    "2": "Chemistry",
    "description": null,
    "3": null,
    "ordering": "5",
    "4": "5",
    "published": "1",
    "5": "1"
}, {
    "id": "158",
    "0": "158",
    "parent": "0",
    "1": "0",
    "name": "Empty Category",
    "2": "Empty Category",
    "description": null,
    "3": null,
    "ordering": "17",
    "4": "17",
    "published": "1",
    "5": "1"
}]
```

and here's my code:

```
function printSubCategories(categories) {

    for (var row in categories) {

        rowParsed = jQuery.parseJSON(row);

        var opt = document.createElement('option');

        if (categories.hasOwnProperty(row)) {
            opt.text = rowParsed.name;
            opt.value = rowParsed.id;
        }

        jQuery('#subcategories').append(opt);
    }

}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

**Update**

Tried the following implementation:

```
if (categories.hasOwnProperty(row)) {

    idParsed = jQuery.parseJSON(row.id);
    nameParsed = jQuery.parseJSON(row.name)

    opt.text = idParsed;
    opt.value = nameParsed;
}
```

still not working...

Comment: Can you tell me why are there a lot of line breaks in some part of the property name?

Comment: why do you duplicate all the data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some line breaks in unexpected area of the data. Like, for example, in

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "0": "1",
    "parent": "0",
    "1": "0",
    "name": "Automotive",
    "2": "Automotive",
    "description": null,
    "3": null,
    "ordering": "0",
    "4": "0",
    "pub
lished": "1",
    "5": "1"
}
```

There is a line break in `published` and it's making the JSON invalid. Removing all those line breaks should make the JSON valid and can be parsed again.

Test your json here and see if it's a valid json
http://jsonlint.com/

**EDIT:**

Okay, I've tried the code on jsfiddle which then made me realize how the json is actually formatted. You have some objects in an array, so that means you simply need to loop the array and then access the object as you would normally.

see this jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/vErj4/

Comment: good eye, but that's not the issue: the person who formatted my post did that by accident. I just validated and it's valid json.

Comment: @Holland take a look at the jsfiddle. I believe I've found the solution

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked for me...

```
var myObj = [
{
    "0": "1",
    "1": "0",
    "2": "Automotive",
    "3": null,
    "4": "0",
    "5": "1",
    "id": "1",
    "parent": "0",
    "name": "Automotive",
    "description": null,
    "ordering": "0",
    "published": "1"
},
{
    "0": "2",
    "1": "0",
    "2": "Aerospace",
    "3": null,
    "4": "1",
    "5": "1",
    "id": "2",
    "parent": "0",
    "name": "Aerospace",
    "description": null,
    "ordering": "1",
    "published": "1"
},
{
    "0": "3",
    "1": "0",
    "2": "Agricultural",
    "3": null,
    "4": "2",
    "5": "1",
    "id": "3",
    "parent": "0",
    "name": "Agricultural",
    "description": null,
    "ordering": "2",
    "published": "1"
},
{
    "0": "4",
    "1": "0",
    "2": "Audiovisual",
    "3": null,
    "4": "3",
    "5": "1",
    "id": "4",
    "parent": "0",
    "name": "Audiovisual",
    "description": null,
    "ordering": "3",
    "published": "1"
},
{
    "0": "5",
    "1": "0",
    "2": "Construction",
    "3": null,
    "4": "4",
    "5": "1",
    "id": "5",
    "parent": "0",
    "name": "Construction",
    "description": null,
    "ordering": "4",
    "published": "1"
},
{
    "0": "6",
    "1": "0",
    "2": "Energy",
    "3": null,
    "4": "6",
    "5": "1",
    "id": "6",
    "parent": "0",
    "name": "Energy",
    "description": null,
    "ordering": "6",
    "published": "1"
},
{
    "0": "7",
    "1": "0",
    "2": "Electronics",
    "3": null,
    "4": "7",
    "5": "1",
    "id": "7",
    "parent": "0",
    "name": "Electronics",
    "description": null,
    "ordering": "7",
    "published": "1"
},
{
    "0": "8",
    "1": "0",
    "2": "Electrical",
    "3": null,
    "4": "8",
    "5": "1",
    "id": "8",
    "parent": "0",
    "name": "Electrical",
    "description": null,
    "ordering": "8",
    "published": "1"
},
{
    "0": "9",
    "1": "0",
    "2": "Entertainment",
    "3": null,
    "4": "9",
    "5": "1",
    "id": "9",
    "parent": "0",
    "name": "Entertainment",
    "description": null,
    "ordering": "9",
    "published": "1"
},
{
    "0": "10",
    "1": "0",
    "2": "Manufacturing",
    "3": null,
    "4": "9",
    "5": "1",
    "id": "10",
    "parent": "0",
    "name": "Manufacturing",
    "description": null,
    "ordering": "9",
    "published": "1"
},
{
    "0": "11",
    "1": "0",
    "2": "Medical",
    "3": null,
    "4": "11",
    "5": "1",
    "id": "11",
    "parent": "0",
    "name": "Medical",
    "description": null,
    "ordering": "11",
    "published": "1"
},
{
    "0": "12",
    "1": "0",
    "2": "Marine",
    "3": null,
    "4": "12",
    "5": "1",
    "id": "12",
    "parent": "0",
    "name": "Marine",
    "description": null,
    "ordering": "12",
    "published": "1"
},
{
    "0": "13",
    "1": "0",
    "2": "Home Applicances",
    "3": null,
    "4": "13",
    "5": "1",
    "id": "13",
    "parent": "0",
    "name": "Home Applicances",
    "description": null,
    "ordering": "13",
    "published": "1"
},
{
    "0": "14",
    "1": "0",
    "2": "Software",
    "3": null,
    "4": "14",
    "5": "1",
    "id": "14",
    "parent": "0",
    "name": "Software",
    "description": null,
    "ordering": "14",
    "published": "1"
},
{
    "0": "15",
    "1": "0",
    "2": "Theoretical work",
    "3": null,
    "4": "15",
    "5": "1",
    "id": "15",
    "parent": "0",
    "name": "Theoretical work",
    "description": null,
    "ordering": "15",
    "published": "1"
},
{
    "0": "16",
    "1": "0",
    "2": "Railroad",
    "3": null,
    "4": "16",
    "5": "1",
    "id": "16",
    "parent": "0",
    "name": "Railroad",
    "description": null,
    "ordering": "16",
    "published": "1"
},
{
    "0": "77",
    "1": "0",
    "2": "Chemistry",
    "3": null,
    "4": "5",
    "5": "1",
    "id": "77",
    "parent": "0",
    "name": "Chemistry",
    "description": null,
    "ordering": "5",
    "published": "1"
},
{
    "0": "158",
    "1": "0",
    "2": "Empty Category",
    "3": null,
    "4": "17",
    "5": "1",
    "id": "158",
    "parent": "0",
    "name": "Empty Category",
    "description": null,
    "ordering": "17",
    "published": "1"
}];

$.each(myObj, function(k, v) {
var opt = document.createElement('option');
$(opt).attr('value', v.id).html(v.name).appendTo($('#mySelect'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ciriusrob/z5LaD/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you're doing too much parsing and checking. If the object you described above is created properly in Javascript, you shouldnt need to use parsing functions. These are only really needed when the object is retrieved via PHP or from the DOM as a string.

You didnt specify what `categories` is. I dont know whether its the array of objects or each iteration of the array of objects, but either way I think you just have too many steps. To do this you should only need this...

...assuming `categories` is the entire array of objects

```
for(var obj in arr){
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  if(obj['id'] && obj['name']){
    opt.text = obj['id'];
    opt.value = obj['name'];
  }
  $('#subcategories').append(opt);
}
```

Comment: I should have specified that the array IS from a php database call.

Comment: ok, in that case, first try only calling JSON.parse() once on the initial array of objects, you wont need to call it on each iteration. Once you do this, console.log() the result of that and see what is coming up, this could help tell whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=0; i < categories.length; i++) {

        rowParsed =categories[i];

        var opt = document.createElement('option');

        if (rowParsed.id && rowParsed.name) {
            opt.text = rowParsed.name;
            opt.value = rowParsed.id;
        }

        jQuery('#subcategories').append(opt);
}
```

or you can use `$.each`, it would be better.

Comment: I tried that method already, and unfortunately it's not working. I forgot to mention that the data received has come from a PHP database call.

Comment: how exactly `$.each` would be better ?